# Redefine null value to string

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Try to study ember...

As this

[image: see],

backend returned some properties with `null` value

How to transform this false value too .. for example, string like "n/a"

Comment: Why do you even want to transform a `null` String to `n/a`? Something like that is clearly a thing you should process in the view. Just write in your template something like `{{if sector sector 'n/a'}}`.

Comment: Because i will use this value in [power select component](http://www.ember-power-select.com/) and it should be transform before. But anyway thank you for your attention, I'm found the answer. It's [transforms](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/models/defining-models/#toc_custom-transforms)

Answer (score 1):

If this transform is applicable to everywhere in client, then [custom tranform](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/models/defining-models/#toc_custom-transforms) is the answer like you mentioned.
Suppose you want to use transform only for the power select dropdown, then before providing `options` to power-select you can modify it as required and then give it to powerselect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [computed properties](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/object-model/computed-properties/) in your controller/component for this:

```
…
 myStringAttr: computed('myAttr', function() {
   if (this.get('myAttr') == null) {
     return "n/a";
   }
   else {
     return this.get('myAttr');
   } 

 })
…
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a computed property:

```
newAttribute: function() {
  const oldAttribute = this.get('oldAttribute')
  return oldAttribute === null ? "n/a" : oldAttribute
}.property('oldAttribute')
```